# while loop in sync function in node js

Tags: node.js, async.js, coinpayments-api

In this code `client.createTransaction()` function returns `result1.txid`. From that `result1.txid` i want  to run **while loop** and inside that **while loop** I want to `client.getTx()` repeatably `untill i get status == 1 or -1`. Here i cant able to run the while loop. It shows nothing,

```
var coinPay = require('coinpayments');
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require("async");

var client = new coinPay({
  'key': 'XYZsdgdfgdf',
  'secret': 'XYZsdfsdfsd',
  'autoIpn': true
});

client.createTransaction({
    'currency1': 'LTCT',
    'currency2': 'LTCT',
    'amount': 1
  }, (err, result1) => {
    while (true) {
      client.getTx(result1.txn_id, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.status == -1) {
          console.log("unsuccesful");
          return;
        } else if (result.status == 1) {
          console.log("succesful");
          return;
        } else
          console.log("checking");
      })
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: ok please share a link in comment.

Comment: instead of wasting mine and your time you could have ignored or answered my question as per code. we are learning developer not a phd guys who are being lazy. so please if u your planing to duplicate the question atleast mention your view that can be understandably with my question

Comment: Use async await

Comment: can you help me with an example? please i have tried async await

Comment: Did you read the duplicate?  It explains why you can't use a `while()` loop like that in Javascript because you can't get any events while you're in the `while` loop, thus no async callbacks will ever get called.  What did you not understand about the duplicate?  Welcome to stack overflow, but the protocol here is that when we see a question that we've seen many answers to before, we are not supposed to repeat the same type of answer over and over - we are supposed to mark it a duplicate. That's how this place is supposed to work.  If you don't understand something in the dup, you can comment.

Comment: Other potentially useful references: [How the event loop and Ajax calls work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575589/how-does-javascript-handle-ajax-responses-in-the-background/7575649#7575649), [Never ending while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676709/javascript-what-is-wrong-with-this-while-loop-never-ending-loop/38676722#38676722), [Asynchronous operations inside a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790159/use-settimeout-inside-while-loop-in-node-js/49791567#49791567).

Comment: More references: [While loop with async Ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332049/while-loop-with-jquery-async-ajax-calls/19332078#19332078), [Looping waiting for async result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494256/how-to-make-decisions-based-on-return-value-of-async-calls/41494768#41494768), [How to synchronize a sequence of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506).

Comment: More references: [Javascript callback within while loop does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175353/javascript-callback-within-a-while-loop-does-not-work), [Javascript while loop waits for increment instead of becoming infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937588/javascript-while-loop-waits-for-increment-instead-of-becoming-an-infinite-loop)